# cannot import submodule from a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, package

I am having following structure for my project

```
Object_Detection/
                 setup.py
                 setup.cfg
                 requirement.txt
                 object_detection/
                                  models
                                  __init__.py #contains from . import models
                 tests/ 
                       # inside tests dir
                       test_utils_image.py
                       __init__.py #empty
                 utils/
                      # inside utils dir
                      __init__.py #inside 
                      utils_image_preprocess.py
                      utils_image.py
                      utils_tfrecord.py
```

Now **init**.py inside utils directory contains the following code.

```
# inside __init__.py
from . import utils_image_preprocess
from . import utils_image
from . import utils_tfrecord
```

Running above **init**.py files gives me an error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

test_utils.py inside tests dir contains the following code

```
# inside test_utils.py
from object_detection.utils import utils_image
```

While running test_utils.py I got the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'utils_image' from 'object_detection.utils'
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder) and [this](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent) and tried to follow every aspect mentioned there but details about what to put inside **init**.py is not clear.

This problem seems to be associated with the structuring of **init**.py in different dir.

I have gone through various and got to know that if we keep even an empty **init**.py file then things will work out but I am not sure about my understanding.

Please let me know

1. what I am missing here and whether I am following the correct structure for packaging my code or not?
2. How to resolve these two errors?
3. Is this issue related to setting up source in IDE as I am using Vscode and I have also seen this has been mentioned at many places. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709973/vscode-1-39-x-python-3-7-x-importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-kn)? (But also tried the same code with PyCharm and encountered same error )

Comment: For me, I have a package named: object_detection installed. add sys.path.insert(0, 'the file dir'), not sys.path.append(), solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to say ...

```py
from object_detection.utils import utils_image
```

... then clearly the **utils** directory must be a subdirectory of the **object_detection** directory and *not* a sibling directory, i.e. at the same level.

Now for your other error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

You did not really specify under what circumstances you get this error other than saying "Running above **init**.py files gives me an error:". But *how* are you "running" these py files or what does that even mean?

If you are executing a script when this occurs (how else would you be getting this error?), the script must be invoked as a module (because scripts cannot have relative imports -- see below) as follows (we will assume that the script you are trying to execute is **test_utils_image.py**):

First, the parent directory of **object_detection**, which is **Object_Detection**, must be in the system path of directories to be searched for finding modules and packages referenced in `import` statements. *In general*, this can be accomplished several ways, for instance

1. The script you are executing is in **Object_Detection** (the directory of the script is automatically added to the `sys.path` list of directories to be searched by the interpreter).
2. Dynamically appending **Object_Detection** to the `sys.path` list of directories at runtime by your script.
3. Appending **Object_Detection** to the **PYTHONPATH** environment variable.

Item 1 above would not be applicable for this specific case since the module we are executing by definition is not in the **Object_Detection** directory.

Note that if your classes will eventually be installed with `pip`, then **site-packages** will be the parent directory of **object_detection**, which is already in `sys.path`.

Then you can execute your script as:

```
python -m tests.test_utils_image
```

If you want to execute this .py file as a script, for example by right-mouse clicking on it is VS Code, then see [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time), in particular the section **Scripts can't import relative**, which says it all -- it cannot work!

**To invoke this as a script, just convert the relative imports to absolute imports.** In fact, the [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a directory inside a package ends up on `sys.path`):

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your answer.
In my case, I am following python package creation practice to create a package where there must be two folders with
the same name. So in my case, test_utils is a sub-directory of Object_Detection (and also at the same level for the object detection). Keeping this in mind, how to resolve this issue now? Do you want me to put the test in object_detection(2nd directory)?
If yes, then what will the way if I don't want to put this under object_detection(2nd directory)

I am running my script by going to __init__.py inside vscode and run in terminal

Comment: If you want to check my running style then how to accomplish this by following default steps in vs code? (running by right-clicking)

You suggested 3 approaches for a successful run of the script
1) having Object_Detection being the current working directory: I moved to Object_Detection and ran my script. Got the same error
2) appending Object_Detection to the sys.path list of directories at runtime. : I write it in my code to specify the path and it worked fine
but how to do this at runtime, I don't know. Please help

Comment: 3) appending Object_Detection to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.: Ok fine but what if I make a package out of this,
Does the user also need to specify this PyTHONPATH before running it?

Comment: Actually, **Object_Detection** and **object_detection`** are not the same names (at least *not* if you are running under Linux/Unix). But no matter if you are running under say Windows. And if you want to have **test** at the same level as **object_detection**, that's OK with me. So as far as your first comment goes, I don't believe there are any issues.

Comment: As I said in my answer, once this package is installed, there will be a new directory **object_detection** under directory **python_install_directory/lib/site_packages** (if it is installed globally), which is in the `sys.path` list (that is how all packages installed with `pip` are found) and so there is nothing necessary for you to do.  The simplest thing to test this would be for you to just install this. Or you can in your script: `import sys; sys.path.append(full-path-to-Object_Detection)` and then you can do your imports.

Comment: Is including sys.path.append in the code a standard way to write while creating python package?  it is solving my problem in case I call my python script from terminal (i.e. without going into utils/__init__.py file ) but if I go to utils/__init__.py file then I am getting the same error even after adding sys.path.  Also, I tried using multiple paths for pythonpath i.e one is already defined for virtual environment and the other I specified is ./Users/object_detection but still calling things from inside script is not working. Can you please explain this a bit? This wil be of enormous hlp 4 me

Comment: Also instead of writing sys.path for every .py file in object_detection is there any way to make object_detection a part of sys.path every time I call any file within this? Will using python path solve this problem (in case I don't want to use sys. path)? What is the best practice to handle these import scenario while building packages? Please guide. Also thank you so much for all your efforts. Learnt a lot today

Comment: No, I can't say it's *usual* to update `sys.path` dynamically at runtime. While you are testing just set **PYTHONPATH** or if you are using a development environment that has a facility for specifying directories to search, add the parent directory there. Or simply install the package with `pip` (you can install it  locally with the **--user** option).

Comment: But If you ever weren't  going to be installing your package using `pip` *and* if all your scripts were in a common directory *and* you knew where the location of the parent directory for you package was *relative* to your scripts, it would be relatively simple to compute the absolute path to that parent directory and update `sys.path` as the very first thing the scripts do. For example, if the directory to be added was in the grandfather directory: `import sys; import os; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__ ) + '/../../Object_Detection'))`

Comment: Thanks a ton for answering all my queries. Just last concern, I tried setting up PYTHONPATH to object_detection and also added object_detection to workspace but if I am running __init__.py it is giving me the same "parent package error". I don't know whether this is the correct approach or not but want to know what is the way that I need to follow in case I want to run by code (using relative reference ) by going into __init__.py  (I am running the file by righ-clicking in vscode and selecting run in terminal) .

Comment: You do not run `__init__.py` files. They exist to signify a *package* as a opposed to just a *module* and its purpose is to initialize the package when you *import the package in a script (they can be empty)*. That script is what you run from outside the package even if it is one of the member .py files in the package. From within the package directories you have to run it as a module, i.e. *python -m tests.script_name*. If you must run it as a script from within the package (by right-clicking?), *then you will have to get rid of the relative imports; but they are not that necessary*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234060/discussion-between-learner-and-booboo).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do the following?

inside your `utils` `__init__.py` import your modules as follows:

```
from .utils_image_preprocess import <func1>... <rest of functions/classes you want to import>
from .utils_image import <func1>... <rest of functions/classes you want to import>
from .utils_tfrecord import <func1>... <rest of functions/classes you want to import>
```

And then in your test file do:

```
from object_detection.utils.utils_image import *
```

OR

```
from object_detection.utils.utils_image import <func1>,...
```

Also, make sure you don't have any circular dependencies in your modules. for example importing of function from your tests to your util module and vise versa

Comment: I followed your advice and call all the function inside __init__.py . Then in test_utils_image.py  I called from object_detection.utils.utils_image import *  It is giving ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection.utils.utils_image'

Answer (score 0):

Python3 has [two types of packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages)

1. Regular Packages
2. Namespace Packages

Regular packages contains **init**.py and namespace packages don't need to have **init**.py

Regarding your folder structure, it is correct, no change needed. You just need to import like this

```
from utils import utils_image
```

without mentioning the objects_detection as objects_detection is just a namespace package.

So it would be usefull when you would refer to the utils module from outside the objects_detection folder.

Here what python docs say about the namespace packages:

> A namespace package is a composite of various portions, where each portion contributes a subpackage to the parent package.

[image]

Comment: It is saying ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'. I tried this with init.py and using the structure mentioned by @Joseph in his answer and with empty init.py file. This is not working.

Comment: Interesting, It worked on my local machine. Could you also tell us which directory do you run this module from?

Comment: Does that change anything as long as internal structure and references are preserved? I am running using virtual env and directly by going into the test_utils_image.py file.  I also tried it by restarting my ide but things are the same.

Comment: Alright, I am sorry but It is hard to see what the error is, I have checked on my local machine everything seems to be fine. 
Regardless could you open your terminal, go to directory of objects_detection and run this command `python3` then inside the shell `from tests imort test_utils.image`

Comment: Can you please have a look now? I have updated the entire project structure. There are two directories with the name object_detection. I guess that is the requirement to make a package in python. Is that what caused the error? Can you please validate this at your end and let me know whether things are working fine at your end or not?

Comment: Hey, So yes it is working on my machine with just: `from utils import utils_image` also you have to change the name of your file `test_utils.image.py` to remove the `.` 
***It is very important is that you must execute the code one directory level of Object_Detection. Other wise you need to add path to your project like this `sys.path.append('path/to/Object_Detection')` in your test_utils_image.py module. I will attach resulting image from my terminal in the answer