# Import python module from another package in vs code

Tags: python, import, package

I have a script with the following structure

```
\-A (git repository 1)
  \-B
   somefile1.py
   __init__.py
setup.py
\-C (git repository 2)
newfile1.py
__init__.py
```

I want to use `somefile1.py` in `newfile1.py`, but I can't find a way to import it.

Both these files are in different levels. I can't change the format of these files.
I added from `..A import B` in `newfile1.py`
But it didn't work in VS code.Is there any way to import the `somefile1.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood you have trided this:

```
from ..A.B import somefile1
```

That called Relative import, you can learn more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)`

But in this case absolute import should work too:

```
from A.B import somefile1
```

Comment: I tried this already. But it didn't work

Comment: It was showing 'import could not be resolved'

Comment: From what path did you ran your code where you in the root of your project or somewhere else ?

Comment: I have loaded only the folder C in my vs code. I am currently in folder C

Comment: After some research, the issu you may have should be linked to your environment which may not be setup properly, [this answer may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73307384/18793713)